# How to freeze a folder in linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, freeze

I wanna to freeze a folder in red hat so nobody (even root) can not add file into the folder or change files that exist in the folder already, i tried to make folder read only but this does not work and root user can add files normally as before, please somebody help me to solving this problem.

Comment: This makes no sense. The `root` user by definition can change anything on the system. What are you really trying to do? Even with genius level kernel hacking to force read-only on some arbitrary file, if I have physical access to the computer I can always remove the hard drive, attach it to another computer, and change anything. I can take a chisel to it if I am angry. What is currently happening (to you?) right now that you want to prevent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. By design, in Linux, root ignores existing permissions on all entities. However, what you *can* do is encrypt files so that they can't be read and can't be modified by those who don't know the key. You can't prevent new files from being added, but with both encryption and decryption keys private, you can easily verify if any file is valid.

This also means you can't have either key on your computer!

Answer (score 2):

Create a filesystem in a file (eg: an iso file) containing the files you want in the directory then use a loopback mount to mount it read only onto the directory.

Anybody who tries to modify the filesystem normally (including root) will get a "read-only filesystem" error.